# How to use my Windows Server 2008 as a proxy server?

Tags: vpn, proxy, windows-server-2008, vps

I have a Windows Server 2008 server in Germany which I can connect to using remote desktop connection. I'm using this server as a host for my website.

My problem is some sites and net sources are blocked on my country, and when I want to go to those sites I must login to my remote desktop server.

I'm not very good at networking so I appreciate if you suggest a good resource with step by step instructions and details. I Googled very much but I couldn't find any simple information about **"How to setup and configure a Windows Server 2008 to work as a proxy or VPN connection"**.

Windows, which I'm using at home, is Windows 7.

Comment: Please denote a question with a question mark please don't imply a question. Also didn't have any trouble Googling it as a detailed guide from Microsoft was the first result.http://lmgtfy.com/?q=enable+vpn+on+windows+server+2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup the `Remote Access Service` on a `Server 2008` VM and I found plenty of good resources online. [This](http://www.buchatech.com/2010/06/how-to-setup-vpn-access-on-server-2008/) is the site I used for setting up VPN. In the `Add Roles` wizard you will need to install `Network Policy and Access Services`. On the `Role Services` part of the wizard you need to select the `Routing and Remote Access Services` Node.

One thing to note is that you may need a couple of other services installed to get VPN functionality working efficiently. I also have a physical server running `Server 2008 R2` that has a couple of other services setup to facilitate the VPN Service on my VM. These services include `Active Directory`, `DNS` and `DHCP`. I have an Active Directory group that specifies the users that are allowed to connect to my local network via VPN and DHCP is used to assign IP addresses to the remote connections.

It might be better if you use a Third-Party solution such as `Hotspot Shield` or `OpenVPN`.

Comment: Your answer is more similar to what I was searching for but totally I could not continue setting up a VPN after activating Remote Access Service, I tried your link [here](http://www.buchatech.com/2010/06/how-to-setup-vpn-access-on-server-2008/) here but my server had some problems and error messages which I think I should create another thread of questions to be solved. And would you please describe me why you suggest to use Third-Party solutions? Because I think this should be more simple than what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using **[OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html)**. Refer this [**How-To**](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide) link for further information.

Comment: I'm not really interested to install external application in my windows server because the windows 2008 is basically a server and I think it must have solutions for this job in itself using windows 2008 server services or features or something similar. Any way your solution is useful thanks for your response.